# Netty unit testing: How to test invocations on the Channel object that is part of the passed ChannelHandlerContext?

Tags: java, unit-testing, netty

Part of the behavior of a `ChannelHandler` implementation is that it should send a response after receiving a message. However, the passed `ChannelHandlerContext` does seem to create an internal `Channel` instance that is not equal to the `EmbeddedChannel` instance used in the unit test. So, it is not possible to test from outside that a response has actually been written to the channel.

Here is some code to clarify the problem:

```
public class EchoHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>
{
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception
    {
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(msg);
    }
}

@Test
public void aTest() throws Exception
{
    EchoHandler handler = new EchoHandler();
    EmbeddedChannel channel = spy(new EmbeddedChannel(handler));
    Object anObject = new Object();
    channel.writeInbound(anObject);
    verify(channel, times(1)).writeAndFlush(eq(anObject)); // will fail
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call readOutbound() on the embedded channel?

Comment: @forty-two: because channel.readOutbound() returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as it gets:

```
public class EchoHandlerTest {

    static class EchoHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(msg);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void aTest() throws Exception {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new EchoHandler());
        Object anObject = new Object();
        channel.writeInbound(anObject);
        assertThat(channel.readOutbound(), is(anObject));
    }
}
```